# Automapper define a custom variable used to determine the values of several properties from destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map some DTOs to ui Models. However, one of my DTOs contains a field with serialized data (the serialized data represents another object with properties) that is used to determine the values of several properties of the model.

For example:

```
public class SourceDTo
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Name {get; set;}
  public string SerializedDetails {get; set;} 
}

public source DestinationModel
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Name {get; set;}
  public string Address {get; set;}
  public string AccountNr {get; set;}
}
```

So in this case, when mapping the source to destination, I would like to be able to deserialize the SerializedDetails field first and then use it in order to map Address and AccountNr with properties from that object, instead of deserializing it twice, for each property. Can this be done with AutoMapper?

Comment: Have you tried looking at ResolveUsing? You can deserialise as part of that.

Comment: Apparently, from automapper 8.0, ResovleUsing was replaced by MapFrom. However, I am not sure I understand its functionality very well. Doesn't it still apply per member? I would somehow want to deserialize the SerializedDetails into a variable that I can then use for the other 2 members.

Comment: Good point. What about using a type converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the most elegant solution YMMV:

```
CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.prop1
        , opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => context.GetJsonObjectValue<string>("RawMessageJSON", "$.props.prop1")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.prop2
        , opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => context.GetJsonObjectValue<int>("RawMessageJSON", "$.props.prop2")));
```

Helper Extension Method for extracting Json path values from the `JObject`:

```
public static class AutomapperResolutionContextExtensions
{
    public static T GetJsonObjectValue<T>(this ResolutionContext context, string key, string jsonTokenPath)
        => ((JObject)context.Items[key]).SelectToken(jsonTokenPath).ToObject<T>();
}
```

Here's the classes we are mapping:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string RawMessageString { get; set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public JObject RawMessageJSON => JObject.Parse(RawMessageString);
}

public class Bar
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }        
}
```

When calling `Map()` we deserialize the string to a `JObject` and pass it in through in the Items Dictionary:

```
var bar = mapper.Map<Bar>(foo, opt => opt.Items["RawMessageJSON"] = foo.RawMessageJSON);
```

Comment: You can also use `BeforeMap` to set `RawMessageJSON`, either in the `Items` collection or in the source object itself.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I am not sure if it is the best solution, but I actually used AfterMap to manually set the values that depended on the serialized object

Comment: That won't work well with validation, because AM won't know that those members are actuallly mapped. And yes, you _really_ should validate your config :) So, in this sense, a resolver based solution is better.